# Can't connect to facebook chat using xmpphp

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-chat, xmpphp

today I wanted to create a very simple php application to chat to facebook friends, but got strucked, I am using xmpphp for connecting to facebook chat. Below is the code I wrote.

```
<?php
require_once("libs/facebook/src/facebook.php");
require_once("informations/facebook_info.php");
$facebook=new Facebook($config_facebook);
if($facebook->getUser())
{
   //now connect to facebook chat api
   require_once('libs/xmpphp/xmpphp/xmpp.php');
   $accesstoken=$facebook->getAccessToken();
   $con=new XMPPHP_XMPP('chat.facebook.com',5222,'my-id@facebook.com',$accesstoken,'xmpphp','chat.facebook.com');
   $con->useEncryption=false;
   $con->connect();
}
else
{
    header("location:index.php");
}
?>
```

But it is throwing me a warning saying:

> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\wamp\www\libs\xmpphp\xmpphp\XMLStream.php on line 405

Have I missed something?

Comment: I can;t see `fclose` in your code..

Comment: it is thrown from the core class itself, not coded by me...

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass **`NULL`** params to **`fclose()`**. Send the handle as a parameter to it.

Something like this

```
<?php

$handle = fopen('somefile.txt', 'r');

fclose($handle);

?>
```

Comment: that part of code contains, the following code
if ($updated === false) {
$this->log->log("Error on stream_select()", XMPPHP_Log::LEVEL_VERBOSE);if ($this->reconnect) {
          $this->doReconnect();
        } else {
          fclose($this->socket);
          $this->socket = NULL;
          return false;
        }

Comment: You can suppress the warning with `@fclose($this->socket);` if everything fails. But i don't suggest that. Can you post the `fopen()` ?

Comment: there is no fopen at all, can you go and see xmpphp class first, its complicated, i dont understand it all...